# How do I intercept Castle Windsor's component resolution to override dependencies?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm looking for a way to hook into Castle Windsor's resolution process so that I can do something like:

```
if (componentCanBeResolvedElsewhere)
{
    return elsewhere.Resolve<TService>();
}
else
{
    windsorContainer.Resolve<TService>();
}
```

I want Castle Windsor to handle the majority of my dependencies, but I want to provide an ability to 'fill-in the blanks'.

I'm sure this can be done, but I'm struggling to find examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [dependency resolvers](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/resolvers.md) which let you declare that you have a special way of solving components. Here is a sample I use to resolve strings from application settings

```
public class AppSettingsResolver : ISubDependencyResolver
{
    public bool CanResolve(
                CreationContext context,
                ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver,
                ComponentModel model,
                DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[dependency.DependencyKey])
               &&
               TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(dependency.TargetType)
                .CanConvertFrom(typeof(string));
    }

    public object Resolve(
                    CreationContext context,
                    ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver,
                    ComponentModel model,
                    DependencyModel dependency)
    {
        return TypeDescriptor
            .GetConverter(dependency.TargetType)
            .ConvertFrom(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[dependency.DependencyKey]);
    }
}
```

You then register the resolver in your castle container:

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new AppSettingsResolver())
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do it via a [Handler Selector](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/handler-selectors.md).

Comment: no problem: I'm trying to look into what difference exists between the two: reading the following at the moment: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.How-Dependencies-Are-Resolved.ashx

Comment: The link that @samy posted can now be found here: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/how-dependencies-are-resolved.md